# Why this function always returning false?

Tags: php, function

I have a very basic question. It's may very poor question but I just want to clear my confusion.

```
function check_array($user_value,$array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($value==$user_value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        //return false;
    }
```

Why this function always returning false.

for example If I have `$numbers = array(1,2,3)`. If I match 2 with this array it should return me true else return me false. But why it's returning always false ?

Comment: You're using return within `foreach` so what actually will be done over here is it'll check the condition if it sets `true` then it'll get `exited` from the function with `true` else it'll get exited with `false`

Comment: Here if true it also returning false.

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/lilq8). When you place `return` within your code then the code get `exited` from there only and no more code gets executed after that

Comment: keep return false out of your loop.....

Comment: @rahul He already tried it and he also have it in his code i dont know then why he is wasting time

Comment: Let me clear again my question is "why this if else condition not working in foreach loop ?" Why I have to write it outside of loop ?

Answer (score 2):

The return false is in the wrong place, it should be where you commented it out but not in the other place it is.

```
function check_array($user_value,$array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($value==$user_value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If the return is in the other place, it will return false after failing to find your value in the first array cell.

Comment: I added comment because I have tried it and get ans. My question is what is the wrong in loop ?

Answer (score 2):

> why it's returning always false ?

Try to "execute" this function yourself acting as a computer.

If the first element of array is equal to `$user_value`, it will return true. If not - it will move futher down the loop and return false.

Probably, you wanted to check all the elements of array for equality. In this case you need to use this:

```
function check_array($user_value,$array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($value==$user_value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean If I write return true in loop, it's only checking for 1st element ? and If I put return false out of array that means it's checking with all element like i++ ?

Comment: Yes it'll check until it won't get `true` or finally `false` but if your array has redundant value something like `array(1,2,3,2)` then also it'll return `true` for the first one only

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to create a function for it when php has already have it [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

you can use it like in a single line

```
$result = in_array($user_value,$array)
```

It will return true if the value is found and false if not found.
You need not to loop through the array

Comment: I know it ! I have made a example for clear this basic programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You have the return false inside of the loop. That means if the first element isn't a match, it will return false. It won't even check the second element of your array

Comment: If it match then what will happen ? return true ? but it's returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will be returning false, unless it matches the first value in the array.

This is because at the moment your logic is in the wrong order, and if the first value in the array doesn't match $user_value the function returns false.

You could solve this problem by moving the `return false;` line of code below the loop. 
Now the loop will run through all the values in the array. It will return true if it matches one, and if it has checked all the values and there is no match then it will then return false.

```
function check_array($user_value,$array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($value==$user_value) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This should clear up the logic mistake in your code. However I up-voted Veerendra's `in_array()` answer as that means there is no need for any loop, cutting down your code.